# AudioKit (still) missing Clock for sequencing Audiofiles

Tags: ios, swift, playback, audiokit

I am trying to playback audiofiles using with the sequencer in AudioKit framework.

```
AudioKit.output = sampler


    AudioKit.start()


    sampler.enableMIDI(midi.client,name: "sampler")


    // sequencer start


    let seq = AKSequencer()


    seq.setLength(AKDuration(beats:Double(4)))


    seq.enableLooping()


    let pattern = seq.newTrack()


    pattern?.setMIDIOutput(sampler.midiIn)


    pattern!.add(noteNumber: 48, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats:Double(1)), duration: AKDuration(beats:Double(0.2)), channel: 0)

    pattern!.add(noteNumber: 48, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats:Double(1)), duration: AKDuration(beats:Double(0.2)), channel: 0)

    pattern!.add(noteNumber: 48, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats:Double(2)), duration: AKDuration(beats:Double(0.2)), channel: 0)


    pattern!.setLoopInfo(AKDuration( beats:Double(4) ), numberOfLoops: 80)

    seq.play()
```

I got to the point where the AKMidiSampler will only play sine waves but not the right sample [as described here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/audiokit/aksequencer%7Csort:relevance/audiokit/ra1O3oqvFJA/QtATJJIdAwAJ)

So as it turns out it is not possible to create sequences "on the fly" so i started to look for workarounds and found [SelectorClock](https://github.com/laurentVeliscek/SelectorClock) Its a workaround from the AudioKit Developers. Sadly this is not working anymore.. many of the class definitions and their properties changed.

Maybe I am not up to date and this is fixed already.. if not I'm sure there must be a go to solution to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on the background capability to your target. 
Choose audio. 
Without this, you get just sine waves.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be completely independent from using AKSequencer you can try the following:

```
let metro = AKMetronome()
metro.tempo = 120.0
metro.frequency1 = 0
metro.frequency2 = 0

metro.callback = {

    // your code e.g.: trigger a AKSamplePlayer() which should have been defined earlier in your code:
    sample.play()

}

AudioKit.output = AKMixer(metro, sample)

try! AudioKit.start()
metro.start()
```

I haven‘t tested this piece of code since I am on my phone right now but it should work. I have this concept running on my iPhone 6s and it works very well. I also tried to replace AKMetronome() with my own class but I haven‘t figured out every single aspect of the sporth parameter yet. I basically want to get rid of initiating any metronome sound ( which is already set to zero in sporth so shouldn‘t produce any noise ) in the first place.. I‘ll let you know in case I‘ll achieve that.